# starting application with custom initial folder

Tags: linux, shell

I am working on linux.

Do you know which command to start an application setting an "initial folder" for it.

If I start my app from a directory that is not the one containing the app itself, some files cannot be found. Is there any shell command to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cd to the directory you would like to start in and then run the program. This can be done in one line like the following:

```
cd /path/to/the/directory; /path/to/./program
```